# How to output original json along with transformed json in JoltTransformation

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I want to save both transformed and original json into Hbase using the same Key. I am using JoltTransformation + EvaluateJsonPath to transform and find an element from transformed json. I want to use this element to save both transformed and original json.

[image]

If I can get original json along with transformed json then I can save both of them using the same key.

Thanks,
Ani

Answer (score 3):

The JoltTransformJson processor only has success and failure relationships, and success is going to be the flow file with the content after the transform. So the only way to get the original content is to route the flow file from before JoltTransformJson, so that it goes to an HBase processor and also to the JoltTransformJson processor.

You could also first insert the original json to hbase then continue on to the transform, so something like:

Source -> PutHBaseJson -> JoltTransformJson -> PutHBaseJson

The first one is inserting the original json, the second one inserting the transformed json. As long as you use the same row id, then they'll be part of the same row.